# Edge slide rotation

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a worm from a reference image be extruding/rotating/scaling circles.

[image]

Is it possible to go back and smooth transition from edge loop to edge loop (e.g. I think the selected loop should be rotated counter clockwise)? Effectively, I think this is a rotation where vertices are restricted to an edge slide.

Comment: I don't think blender supports it yet. It was one of my feature requests for long time. :)

Comment: Btw, is [this](http://youtu.be/-6t6CdH1eMA) what you are exactly looking for?

Comment: @LeonCheung Yep, exactly it

Comment: If the rotation is small enough, doing a median-pivot rotation locked to the view zed axis might be sufficient. Another option might be creating a tube of parallel circles and shrinkwrapping it to the worm, or some similar retopo maneuver:

Comment: I've posted a feature request for this [here](https://rightclickselect.com/p/modeling/6jbbbc/edge-slide-rotation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this feature is not currently implemented in Blender.